# Creating a button with mulitple layers to it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im making a game in libgdx and I was wondering if there was a way to have different layers to a button.  For instance I take an image create a button out of it but I want to have stars on top of it to indicate whether the level was completed.  Is there anyway of doing this in libgdx/can anyone point me in the right direction?  Ive searched around but havnt found anything concrete yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such button. However there is [ImageButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html). You could just use your standard image, and when the level is completed, you will change the whole image to one that has stars on it.

Another, maybe more powerful alternative would be to create your own `MultipleImageButton extends ImageButton`. It would not just have a single image, but a List of images. All you would have to do is override the [`ImageButton.draw(Batch, float)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch,%20float%29) method and render all images at once, instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and the solution of noone worked :

```
public class MultipleImageButton extends ImageButton {

private Texture type;
private float h;
private float w;

public MultipleImageButton(Skin skin, String styleName, Texture type) {
    super(skin, styleName);
    this.type = type;
    h = type.getHeight();
    w = type.getWidth();
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    if (super.isPressed()) {
        batch.draw(
                type,
                super.getX() + super.getWidth() / 2 - w / 2,
                super.getY() + super.getHeight() / 2 - h / 2
                        + super.getStyle().pressedOffsetY, w, h);

    } else {
        batch.draw(type, super.getX() + super.getWidth() / 2 - w / 2,
                super.getY() + super.getHeight() / 2 - h / 2, w, h);
    }

}

public void resize(float height, float width) {
    this.h = height;
    this.w = width;
}
}
```